# Delphi - TTakePhotoFromCameraAction - App crash API 33

Tags: android, delphi, permissions, camera, firemonkey

I want to give camera authorization with the native android Popup and click "Yes".

```pascal
procedure TFormModuleCreationFraisDivers.btnTakePictureClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Demande les autorisations pour prendre la photo du frais divers
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([PERM_CAMERA], PermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale);
end;

procedure TFormModuleCreationFraisDivers.PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
var perm: TPermissionStatus;
begin
  for perm in AGrantResults do
    if perm <> TPermissionStatus.Granted then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Les autorisations requises n''ont pas étés accordées');
      Exit;
    end;

  actTakePic.Execute
end;

procedure TFormModuleCreationFraisDivers.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);

  TDialogService.ShowMessage(msg, procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
  begin APostRationaleProc; end);
end;
```

MANIFEST :

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I have tried to add:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

But same problem.

Comment: Yes, I have remove them, but same result

Comment: I have edit my post, now my app crash after accept camera permission, I have check in app info and Camera is granted

Comment: In your post we read that the permission is not granted. Confusing. And we have no idea (you did not tell) what you do that lets your app crash.

Comment: I click on a button wich trigger btnTakePictureClick event, then I accept the Popup that told if I want to accept permission to camera, I click Yes, Then Crash

Comment: You should post the used code. And the relevant lines from the logcat. Tell which exception that you did not catch lets your app crash.

Comment: You have one of 2 options: If you have access to the Delphi 12 beta (Yukon), use that, otherwise use a modified copy of `FMX.MediaLibrary.Android` that does not rely on the old permissions

Comment: I have tried to remove the old permissions in `FMX.MediaLibrary.Android`, clean and build, but same error, it seems the modified file is not taken into account

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try add this unit to your project
https://github.com/dondonondon/FMXDesignTemplateAndroid/blob/main/Template%20v3%20(Alexanderia%20%26%20Athens%20-%20V.0.1%20Simple%20Demo)/sources/libraries/FMX.MediaLibrary.Android.pas